# How many chocolate chips are required to ensure that 90\% of the $k$ cookies has at least 1 chip?

Tags: probability

There's a cookie dough, and you randomly cut this dough into $k$ equal sized cookies. You want to put $n$ chips so that 90% of the cookies have at least 1 chip.

Does this $90\%$ also represent the the probability that a single cookie has at least 1 chip? If it does, what justifies the equivalence?

Comment: You are expected to have made some effort. Can you tell us what you have tried and where you are stuck up ?

Comment: @trueblueanil This is more of a semantics question. I'm not asking for how to solve the problem, but if my interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It implies that the expected number of cookies with chips would be $90\%$ of all the cookies.

It does not implies that the number of cookies with chips would always be at least $90\%$ of all the cookies. You will never be certain, no matter how many chips you use, and for example there is a small chance all the chips end up in the same cookie.

Nor does it imply that the probability would be at least $90\%$ for the number of cookies with chips being at least $90\%$ of all the cookies. Some batches will have strictly more than $90\%$ of the cookies having chips and to offset this, some batches will have strictly fewer than $90\%$ of the cookies having chips.

For example, suppose there are $k=10$ cookies and $n=23$ chocolate chips, with each chip placed independently uniformly at random in one of the cookies.  The probability that a particular cookies has no chips is $\left(1 -\frac{1}{k}\right)^n \approx 0.0886$ in this example.  So each cookie has a probability over $91\%$ of having a chip.

But the probability that at least $9$ of the $10$ cookies have chips is less than $80\%$.  Here is a simulation in R illustrating this, with each of the $10^5$ runs simulating how many cookies receive chips:

```
set.seed(2021)
cookieswithchips <- replicate(10^5, length(table(sample(10, 23, replace=TRUE))))
mean(cookieswithchips)
# 9.11145
table(cookieswithchips) 
# cookieswithchips
# 5     6     7     8     9    10 
# 1   164  2671 17613 44955 34596
```

Comment: Right, I do understand that the expected number of cookies with chips would be $90\%$. But does it mean that if we pick a single cookie, the probability of it having a chip should be $90\%$?

Comment: @anonuser01 - yes: assuming there is nothing special about your selection of a cooking (you do not look at it to see how many chips it has before picking it), then the  expected number of cookies with chips being  $90\%$ is the same statement as the probability of a randomly selected cookie having a chip being $90\%$

Comment: Formally, I think that comes from the linearity of expectation of IID indicator variables, where $I_i$ is 1 if the i-th cookie has at least one chip and zero otherwise? So $E[I_1 + \ldots I_{100}] = 100 E[I_i] = 100 * p = 90 \implies p = 0.9$

Comment: @anonuser01 - yes, though you do not need independence (and here, since the chips go somewhere, you do not have it)